# GraphQL Strapi - how to query with where clause using array of IDs?

Tags: graphql, strapi

I'm using Strapi GraphQL as a backend for my Nuxt app, and am trying to perform a query where I find images using an array of IDs. Right now, supplying an empty array returns all images when instead I need the query to return an empty array of Images.

**images.gql:**

```
query($ids:[ID]) {
  images(where:{id:$ids}) {
    id
    name
    slug
    src {
      url
      formats
    }
  }
}
```

**query variables:**

```
{
  "ids": [] <-------- returns all images; need to return empty array of Images
}
{
  "ids": [6] <--------- returns image with ID of 6 correctly
}
```

Looking at the [Strapi documentation](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/plugins/graphql.html#filters) I've also tried other filters such as `[field]_in` but that is still returning all Images instead of an empty array.

Does anyone have a suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: use some surely not existing id ?

Comment: That... is kind of brilliant. I don't know why I didn't think of that! I can write a conditional that supplies "-1" as an ID if I want to return an empty array. Thanks!